# error when I write the arabic tex

Tags: errors

```
\mtctitle undefined. \select@language {arabic}
\mtctitle undefined. \begin{document}
```

When I compile the tex the error happens:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}% استخدام الالوان
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}% حزمة كتابة المعادلات الكيميائية
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Simplified Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.15]{Simplified Arabic}
\usepackage{graphicx}%ادراج الصور
\graphicspath{{image/}}
\usepackage{import}
% تعليمات تغير العنوان للفصول%
\addto\captionsarabic{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{الفصل}%
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{الفهرس}%
 \renewcommand{\mtctitle}{قائمة المحتويات}
  }
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or الأول
\or الثاني 
\or الثالث 
\or الرابع
\or الخامس
\or السادس
\or السابع
\or الثامن
\or التاسع
\or العاشر 
\else
I need more words\fi}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}%% uncomment if 'etoolbox' isn't already being loaded
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
\title {\LR{colud point}}
\begin{document}
\import{./titlepage/}{titlepage.tex}
\chapter*{الخلاصة}
\import{./Abstract/}{Abstract.tex}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{المقدمة}
\begin{enumerate}
\item{التحليل الكيميائي\LR{Chemical Analysis}}
\\
\import{./Introduction/}{Introduction1.tex}
\item{الفصل في الكيمياء التحليلية\LR{Separation in analytical chemistry}}
\\
\import{./Introduction/}{Introduction2.tex}
\item{الاستخلاص بالمذيب\LR{Solvent Extraction method}}
\\
\import{./Introduction/}{Introduction3.tex}
\item{ الاستخلاص وحالة التوازن الكيميائي}
\\
\import{./Introduction/}{Introduction4.tex}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item{الاستخلاص عن طريق تكوين المعقدات المخلبية\LR{Chelate complex}}
        \import{./Introduction/}{Introduction5.tex}
          \item{الاستخلاص عن طريق تكوين المعقدات المخلبية\LR{Chelate complex}}

\end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\mtctitle` is defined in the `minitoc` package, which you don't load. You have two options:

- If you don't need the `minitoc` package, just remove the line  `\renewcommand{\mtctitle{...}`.
- If you need the functionality of the `minitoc` package, load it by adding the line

  ```
  \usepackage{minitoc}
  ```

  *before* the line `\usepackage{polyglossia}`.

Some additional notes:

- Move the line `\usepackage{graphicx}` to a place *before* the line `\usepackage{polyglossia}`, e.g. after loading the package `xcolor`.
- Remove `\\` after the `\item{...}` commands; they are responsible for the `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` warnings. You don't tell us the contents of the imported files. I guess leaving an empty line before the `\import` commands also does what you want.